# Kapt works fine from shell but not form intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, kapt2

I have a Annotation Processor in kotlin for generate classes.

When I use gradle build in shell, all works fine, but IntelliJ don't generate them. It ignore completly the kapt module.

The module es https://github.com/MiguelAngelLV/kspring

In build.gradle of my project I have:

```
group 'proyect'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    ext.springBootVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlin_version}")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


allOpen {
    annotation("org.malv.kspring.spring2swagger.REST")
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}



sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "${buildDir.absolutePath}/tmp/kapt/main/kotlinGenerated/"
        }
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}



dependencies {
...

    kapt 'com.github.MiguelAngelLV:kspring:3cf6e7773e'
    implementation 'com.github.MiguelAngelLV:kspring:3cf6e7773e'

....


}
```

The AllOpen plugin from Spring works fine, but kotlin-kapt does not work.

If make "gradle build" in the shell, gradle generate the classes and IntelliJ compile fine, but if I erase them and press in build, the build fail because the classes don't exists